# Unix awk command

Tags: unix, awk

please help me in understanding below awk command:

```
awk -v var1=$1 -v var2=$2 '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2; /^var1 var2/' $READ_FILE | awk '{print $3}'
```

I saw this command in the post : [awk command to accept two variables as parameters and return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569066/awk-command-to-accept-two-variables-as-parameters-and-return-a-value?rq=1)

What is the purpose of '`$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2; /^var1 var2/`' in above command.

Comment: I wonder if this one-liner is correct.. just print each matched line? (before the `;`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
awk -v var1="$1" -v var2="$2" '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2; /^var1 var2/' "$READ_FILE"
```

It means that inside awk `var1` becomes the shell variable `$1` and `var2` becomes `$2`. Inside awk (inside the single quotes) there are also `$1` and `$2` and they mean field 1 and field 2 on every line in the input file. If the first field (`$1`) if matched by the regular expression in the string in `var1` and likewise for `$2` and `var2`, then `$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2` evaluates to 1 and the corresponding line of the input file gets printed.

`/^var1 var2/` means if a line starts with the string "var1 var2" then print the line (probably meant to print the header)...

Comment: no it shouldn't! `$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2` is unpercise to a degree not meeting the specification and `/^var1 var2/` is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @mikyra What do you mean? No it should not what? I have only attempted to explain to the OP what it means, not whether it is a good solution. Yes it is imprecise, but that may be intentional. `/^var1 var2/` is not necessarily wrong by the way, but it has nothing to do with the variables `var1` and `var2`

Comment: sry, I just got stuck on the "It should be:" intro as it might lead to the conclusion the following example might be the one the use. Probably "The way the author presumably intended it to work" or something like that wouldn't have made me such alert.

Comment: As I think it's misleading with the introduction given as already explanation, yes for sure.

Comment: @mikyra I think you are mistaken. The OP literally asks for help in understanding an awk command and what its purpose is and that is what I provided..

Answer (score -1):

While still working for the purpose named in your link.

EDIT: as i just see your linked entry seems to have been fixed in the meantime.

The command is in deed a little bit overcomplicated and (in a certain degree) even incorrect as you already suspected.

To understand what the line line `$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2; /^var1 var2/` is intended to do you have to understand two important facts first.

- if no command is given but a pattern matches `awk` will print the whole line that matched even without an explicit print statement
- if given from the command line multiple patterns have to be separated by `;`

Bot parameters to be tested are passed in via the `-v` switch one getting the awk-variable `var1` and the other the awk variable `var2`

`$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2` will test if *both* (thats what the `&&` operator is used for) the 1st field matches the regular expression stored in var1 (`~` being the relavant operator here) and the 2nd field matches the regular expression stored in var2.

The second statement `/^var1 var2/` is as superfluous as it is incorrect.
As this would match a line starting with the **literal** "var1" in followed by the **literal** string var2.

It doesn't hurt too much in the example given as it won't match any way, yet it is still not correct.

Using the regex match operator `~` instead of a test for equality utilizing `==` is another "unsharpness" the proposed solution adds.

My suggestion would be to just use:

```
awk -v var1="$1" -v var2="$2" '$1==var1 && $2==var2 {print $3}' your-file-here
```

even sparing opening up another pipe just to print the value stored in field number 3.