# awk command - multiple variable to return a variable

Tags: shell, awk

Here's [a link]  [Using awk to find a string in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753410/using-awk-to-find-a-string-in-a-file/25753480?noredirect=1#comment40298884_25753480)

[2 - link] [awk command to accept two variables as parameters and return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569066/awk-command-to-accept-two-variables-as-parameters-and-return-a-value)

Here is the table:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Id   Name      CreationDate         Comment
----------------------------------------------------
1    testing:    19.10.11             created by jag

2    develop    19.10.12             created by jag

3    array      19.10.12             created by jaguuuu

4    start123   19.10.12             created by akj
```

So I referred both of these, what I am trying to do is get the id number from first column and name from second column.

For example, If I take id=1 and name = testing ; if i find in 1st column id =1 and in 2nd column name = testing, then my output shall be testing.

This is the code, I wrote:
a is a variable which has some output stored in it.

```
b=$(echo "$a" | awk -v var1=1 -v var2=testing '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2 {print $2}')
echo "$b"
```

But it not printing out anything. I thought it shall print out testing.

update:
field1::::

```
1    testing:    19.10.11             created by jag
```

In our case,
Input:

```
1    testing:
```

output:

```
 testing:
```

if var1=1 and var 2 = testing both are found in same row just under column1("1") and column2 ("testing:")

Sorry for asking lot of questions - new to it, and trying to learn via writing code.

Note: table is stored in a variable a.

So, this should work:

```
x=$(echo"$a"|awk -v var1=1 -v var2=testing '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2 {print $2}')
echo"$x"
```

But wonder why it is not working. Will check few more stuff like you guys mentioned and get back to you guys tomorrow.

Thanks

Comment: Considering `a="1    testing:"`, the sample code you provided works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `$` in front of variable names to get their value is shell syntax. awk is not shell. Just use the variable name, just like you would in C or most other languages.

```
awk -v var1=1 -v var2=testing '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2 {print $2}'
```

Chances are, though, this is not what you really want to do. Post another question with sample input and expected output and we can show you the right way to do it.

Using the sample input from your updated question:

```
$ cat file
----------------------------------------------------
Id   Name      CreationDate         Comment
----------------------------------------------------
1    testing:    19.10.11             created by jag

2    develop    19.10.12             created by jag

3    array      19.10.12             created by jaguuuu

4    start123   19.10.12             created by akj

$ awk -v var1=1 -v var2=testing '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2 {print $2}' file
testing:
```

Comment: Correct this is not what I want.. It is still not printing anything.

Comment: Then all we can do is wait for you to post sample input and expected output to help us understand what you are really trying to do.

Comment: i tried posting another question, Have to wait 90 minutes. where a is just a variable where my output (table displayed above is stored). let me try to explain here:

Now I want to take one variable which is equal to 1 and other variable equal to testing as displayed in the table in one of the links listed and if they both exist for $1(by$1 i mean column1) and $2 on the same line. it matches and prints out testing. if not it will say no match. 

if/else statement I thought I would add at last after I get the logic going.

Comment: The script i posted would work for the scenario you described so there's something about your input that youre not capturing in your notes. You can always edit your question to add input and output.

Comment: I updated my answer to show it running against your posted input file and it does produce the desired output. There's really only a couple of possibilities: 1) you are using a broken awk, or 2) your input file has control chars in it. For the former, tell us what OS and awk version you are using, for the latter, run `cat -v file` on your input file to see if any control chars show up.

Comment: had exact same thing, but just not printing it.

here is the reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768148/in-shell-for-awk-can-i-have-variable-instead-of-file-path/25768912#25768912

I am not using a file, console output is stored in variable a.
So, using a  echo "a" so in my case it would be:


    x=$(echo"$a"|awk -v var1=1 -v var2=testing '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2 {print $2}')
echo"$x"

Comment: The script should be working given everything you've told us so the problem lies with something you haven't told us so unfortunately you're on your own to debug this further. Try it with just the first var, then with just the second, add some p.rints - all the usual debugging stuff to reduce the script to pinpoint the problem

Comment: this approach help.. 
I shut everything down, and starting everything from scratch. Had a "." in the code somewhere which was not even reaching here. 

thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: You're welcome. This still isn't a good solution to your actual problem though, maybe it'd be useful for you to start again with a new question and the specific input/output?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to come up with another solution. I will invest some time on it and once I am stuck will ask another question. To be honest with you, I am actually learning, I use to be scared of programming. Thanks for the help and patience :)

Comment: I highly recommend the books Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson to learn awk and shell respectively.